# Making Semantic-ui table rows selectable like buttons in Meteor JS

Tags: javascript, css, meteor, semantic-ui

I have created a table using semantic-ui in my Meteor JS web app.
That table displays the list of names that is on my DB.

I would like to make the rows of that semantic-ui table selectable in the true sense and not just selectable in appearance.
At the moment, when the mouse hovers over a row, that row gets highlighted (changes shade) which makes it appear selectable, but when you click on it, it does not call or trigger a javascript function and therefore it is not truly selectable.

How do I make that table truly selectable?

How does one do this?

Is it possible?

or do I just have to add a button beside the texts for each table and have the user click that button instead?

I could add the buttons in each cell but I really would prefer it if the whole row is selectable instead.....

Thank you very much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to add class or id on `<tr>` and then use that class to add function you want to that row. For creating a function you will need to use **meteor template events** and you can learn more about it [here](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/forms-and-events).

I also created an rough example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/efp8z6Ln/) that you can follow, just replace with your own classes and template and file names. :)

I hope that helps you!